# Static-content deploy slow after upgrading

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, static-content-deploy

after upgrading M2 from 2.4.2 to 2.4.5-p1 the static content deployment increased significantly.

The time to deploy increases for every new theme/language.

Used to be ~5min total for all themes to deploy, after upgrading it will take at least 2 hours?

Any idea, or suggestion, to debug which files or what is causing this?

[image]

Comment: To improve overall performance, Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Magento 2.4.2, to speed up static content deployment, specific your theme by using `--theme` option and using `--no-parent` option when running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command. By doing that, Magento only generates your theme, not generate parent themes like `Magento/luma`, `Magento/blank`,...

That equals: don't run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` without any options.

1. For frontend: Assume your frontend theme is: `TuVan/XLuma`, you should run the following command for frontend:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area frontend --theme TuVan/XLuma --no-parent
```

2. For admin:

- Case 1: Assume you use a custom admin theme, it is `TuVan/backend`, you should run the following command for admin:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area adminhtml --theme TuVan/backend --no-parent
```

- Case 2: Assume you are not using any custom admin theme, you should run the following command for admin:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area adminhtml
```

You can read more options for `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/static-view/static-view-file-deployment.html

Comment: I'm still not sure why running the deployment without any options would takes hours, when separately they all run in a few seconds.. might be server related.


However your answer did help, thanks for the information. Running the deployment for our theme only with the no-parent option reduced the deployment back to just one minute.

Comment: @Gerhard Glad to help. I guess your server runs out of memory for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this patch in your project

[ACSD-46815_2.4.5_v2.patch](https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/blob/master/patches/os/ACSD-46815_2.4.5_v2.patch)

[ACSD-46815: static content deploy fails when using compact strategy](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-20/acsd-46815-static-content-deploy-fails-when-using-compact-strategy.html?lang=en)

I use quick strategy, but this patch helped me.